# I have no GUI after signing in

Tags: release-loki, boot, display, desktop

Changed my power settings so that it would do nothing when I shut the lid on my laptop. Then I had to restart to get the settings to work. After that, when I get to the sign-in screen where I can write my password, after I log on I can only see my wallpaper, no dock or activites bar or anything. I can't even access terminal with superkey + T. I'm running Loki.

Comment: You can use ALT+CTRL+F2 to open terminal (also works with F3, F4...). ALT+CTRL+F7 Returns to GUI.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me sometimes as well. I have yet to find the root cause of it or a real fix.

What helps in my case is to press ctrl+alt+F1 to go to a terminal. Log in with your user credentials and type

```
startx
```

to (re)start X.

Then, press ctrl+alt+F7 to go back to your desktop.

As a security precaution, I would recommend (if this works) to go back to ctrl+alt+F1 and type

```
exit
```

to make sure your user is logged out of this terminal environment.